# How to get out of oem

Tags: oem

Dear Ubuntu community,

I purchased a new computer with pre-installed Ubuntu.
Unfortunately, when starting it, it did not ask me to install Ubuntu as it is normally done.
I set up a user profile under my name and gave myself administrator rights, but the computer never even asks for which user it should boot.
Whatever I do is under oem, and this causes real problems. I cannot access properly my documents, it does not always save what I do, and it never requires a password for anything I do in terminal.

I searched a bit on the Net, but I only found people wishing to set up oem, never anyone who wished to get out of it.

Anyone can help me?

Thanks a lot in advance,

Eva

Answer (score 1):

Download an Ubuntu version. Create a bootable USB, boot from it and install Ubuntu. During formatting format the whole disk; either remove all partitions and use it as 1 `/` or a 20,25Gb for `/` and the remainder for `/home/` or a personal partition (I do the latter and all my documents on that).

If there are any documents you need to save do so either now or use the "try Ubuntu" option.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much for your answer.
That was exactly what I wanted to avoid because I had already transferred all my data from my old computer to this one, and that takes some time.
I found another way around it; when clicking "boot with ubuntu" in the boot manager, it sent me to my user name, and now I am logged in with my normal password and all. There is still an oem account somewhere, but I managed to extract all my data and transfer it to my personal account.
Best regards,
Eva

Comment: I made an Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.3 OEM system, added a program package and prepared it for shipping to the end user. Then as end user I set language, created user id and password and checked for left-overs from the `oem` user. The user is not there, and `/home/oem` is not there. In other words, the OEM setup worked for me.

Comment: See [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Ubuntu_OEM_Installer_Overview) (at the bottom of the page), "End User's First Boot: Once the computer is shipped to an end user and is booted for the first time a setup wizard will help set up location, keyboard layout, user name etc." - Anyway, it is possible that the vendor of the computer set up the OEM Ubuntu system incorrectly.